# selecting data from two rows into two columns as output mysql Pivot Table

Tags: mysql

I want to select a collection of pieces of data from four different tables and everything is running smoothly except for one.

```
 ANS_ID     REG_ID  QST_ID  ANS_value
     4      1      11       M
     5      1      12       12/02/1998
     16     15     11       M
     17     15     12       11/08/2005
     28     16     11       F
     29     16     12       05/18/2005
     40     17     11       M
     41     17     12       11/04/1980
     52     18     11       M
```

I need to pull the gender and birthday from this data as the last two columns of the rows, but when I try to include it all my previous rows are doubled, with the gender and birthday alternating.

```
ATT_fname   ATT_lname   sex birthday
Kid1        Kid1Last    M   NULL
Kid1        Kid1Last    NULL    11/8/2005
Kid2        Kid2Last    F   NULL
Kid2        Kid2Last    NULL    5/18/2005
Adult1      Adult1Last  M   NULL
Adult1      Adult1Last  NULL    11/4/1980
```

What I want is this:

```
ATT_fname   ATT_lname   sex birthday
Kid1        Kid1Last    M   11/8/2005
Kid2        Kid2Last    F   5/18/2005
Adult1      Adult1Last  M   11/4/1980
```

Current Code:

```
Select ATT_fname, ATT_lname, ATT_email, concat(ATT_address, ' ', ATT_address2), ATT_city, 
t4.STA_name, ATT_zip, ATT_phone,
case when QST_ID = 11 then ANS_value end as sex,
case when QST_ID = 12 then ANS_value end as birthday
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.ATT_ID = t2.ATT_ID
JOIN table3 t3
ON t3.REG_ID=t2.REG_ID
JOIN table4 t4
ON t4.STA_ID=t1.STA_ID
WHERE t2.EVT_ID = 9999;
```

Comment: apparently none of the formatting sticks around when you submit, sorry for the clutter, also sorry for how much time i spent trying to format that

Comment: Please make some additional effort to format your question into a readable thing.

Comment: You should have a toolbar with formatting buttons; there's also a help button :-) (tl;dr: indent with four spaces to preserve whitespace, which can be done easily by selecting the text and pressing control+K). There is also a preview below the textarea. You can always [edit] a question to fix it (I fixed it for you now).

Comment: Try grouping by `REG_ID`.

Comment: thanks for the edit @Carpetsmoker

Answer (score 0):

So instead of spending another 45 minutes trying to format this (paste would be a great option)  I decided to spend that time solving it.

Just have to join your table twice with two different alias' one for each field you need to bring in ie:

`JOIN Table1 t1sex
ON t1sex.REG_ID=t2.REG_ID AND t1sex.QST_ID=11
JOIN Table1 t1birthday
ON t1birthday.REG_ID=t2.REG_ID AND t1birthday.QST_ID=12`